# Why can't DateTime parse dd.mm.yy always correct?

Tags: php, datetime

I've encountered this weird issue:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('10.10.04');
$date2 = new DateTime('25.03.07');

echo $date1->format('Y-m-d'); // result: 2016-02-15
echo "<br>";
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d'); // result: 2007-03-25
```

Since the format is the same, I can't explain why the first attempt fails, but the second one succeeds. Is there something that I can do about that?

I can't change the format of the date I receive, so I somehow must read the dd.mm.yy date format to finally format it into the Y-m-d format.

Searched around for something related that helps me, but I couldn’t find anything.

Taken from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes), this should be the behavior:

> whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Comment: Because it's ambiguous.... how can DateTime know that it's dd.mm.yy and not mm.dd.yy or yy.mm.dd?

Comment: Use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead to eliminate the ambiguity

Comment: From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php): _"The "Day, month and two digit year, with dots or tabs" format (dd [.\t] mm "." yy) only works for the year values 61 (inclusive) to 99 (inclusive)"_

Comment: @MarkBaker could you add this as an answer please, it worked. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As everyone suggested, try using [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Please check below code:

```
<?php

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y','10.10.04');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y','25.03.07');

echo $date1->format('Y-m-d'); // result: 2004-10-10

echo $date2->format('Y-m-d'); // result: 2007-03-25
?>
```

Output: https://eval.in/518801